# How to send Object via an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a class called DownloadInfo that consists of a progressBar and two textView , how can I send it via intent and maintain the object at the other side ?

Comment: Why would you put a View inside a Java Object (aka POJO)?

Comment: Intent is for some specific operations , go through this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_intents_filters.htm

Comment: only you can send Parcelable obaject or class in your intent

Comment: Can't You make them Static and Access the by it class name from your other activity or by making them Global and access them by object of the class!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Answer (score 1):

Implement `Serializable` to `DownloadInfo` class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Youractivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("downloadInfo", DownloadInfo object);
intent.putExtras(args);
```

On other side:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("downloadInfo"))
    downloadInfo = (DownloadInfo) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("downloadInfo");
```

Comment: Dear @faranjit my downloadInfo object consist of images and progressBar and text ,when I use your code ,  it says .NotSerializableException: android.widget.ImageView , how can i solve it ?

Comment: Please give more detail about what you want to do and some code.